# chrome.tabs.update not going to url, instead going to extension link appended by a url

Tags: javascript, redirect, google-chrome-extension

I have the code

```
executeFinal.onclick = function(element) {
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  console.log("Moving to shop all page");
  chrome.tabs.update(null, ({url:"www.urlexample.com/something"}));  
});
};
```

I expect it to go to www.urlexample.com/something , instead it updates to chrome-extension://cxkbbioshdzuxcuibauisdbwww.urlexample.com/something I assume this is either

A) Something to do with the way I am calling chrome.tabs.update

B) Because I am doing this from popup.js instead of sending a message to background.js

Any advice would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: That is because your URL is missing the schema and it is interpreted as a relative URL. User `"http://www.urlexample.com/something"` or `https://.....`.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that, it worked! Thank you very much!